# Must the ternary operator be evaluated statically whenever possible?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Is it required that the ternary operator be evaluated statically whenever possible, or can the compiler defer it to later, and therefore reject a program which would depend on it being evaluated statically?

More precisely, here's an ambiguous fragment of a program:

```
char b[sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)] = {0};
```

Depending on whether `a` is a variable-length array or not, the fragment is invalid or not. If `a` is a VLA, then `sizeof(a)` is not determined statically, and therefore the initialization cannot take place:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int a[argc];
  char b[sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)] = {0}; // invalid
  return 0;
}
```

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

But if `a` is not a VLA, then everything can be evaluated statically:

```
int main() {
  int a[42];
  char b[sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)] = {0}; // valid
  return 0;
}
```

My question is: are standard-conforming compilers **required** to evaluate statically whenever possible, and therefore **must** accept the second program, or are they allowed to "defer it to dynamic evaluation" and **may** reject it?

Comment: As far as I know the conditional operator is not a constant expression. So the declaration of the array is invalid because you may not initialize a VLA.

Comment: Not checked with standard and therefore no answer... I would say everything depends on the size of the array. If it is a constand expression, it is no VLA and hence can be initialized. I don't think the operator is important in this case. It only depends on the size of `a`. If it is constand, then also size of `b` is constand and known at compile time. I would expect initializing `a` in your first sample should fail in the same way.

Comment: The more interesting case is if `1 ? 10: sizeof(a)` is an ICE.

Comment: "Must the ternary operator be evaluated statically whenever possible?" No, neither do other operators, but that's an entirely different topic from whether or not these operators are allowed to appear in constant expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second case:

```
int a[42];
char b[sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)] = {0};
```

The expression `sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)` is considered a **constant expression** as defined in section 6.6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and is also an **integer constant expression**.

From section 6.6p3 states the constraints on a constant expression:

> Constant  expressions  shall  not  contain  assignment,  increment, 
>   decrement,  function-call, or  comma  operators,  except  when  they
>   are  contained  within  a  subexpression  that  is  not evaluated.

The above expression does not contain any of the disallowed operators.

Section 6.6p6 further details integer constant expressions:

> An integer constant  expression <sup>117)</sup> shall  have  integer  type  and 
>   shall  only  have  operands that   are   **integer   constants**, enumeration   constants,   character   constants, **`sizeof` expressions 
>   whose  results  are  integer  constants**,
>   `_Alignof` expressions,  and  floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.  Cast operators in an integer constant expression 
>   shall  only  convert  arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,  except 
>   as  part  of  an operand to the `sizeof` or
>   `_Alignof` operator .

And footnote 117:

> 117) An  integer  constant  expression  is  required  in  a  number 
>   of  contexts  such  as  the  size  of  a  bit-field member  of  a 
>   structure,  the  value  of  an  enumeration  constant,  **and  the  size
>   of  a  non-variable  length array.**  Further constraints that apply to
>   the integer constant expressions used in conditional-inclusion
>   preprocessing directives are discussed in 6.10.1

Because `a` is not a variable length array, `sizeof(a)` evaluates to an integer constant.  And because `sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)` contains only `10` which is an integer constant,  `sizeof(a)` which evaluates to an integer constant, and the operators `?:` and `>` which are not disallowed operators, the entire expression is considered an **integer constant expression** and can be used as the size of a non-variable length array, meaning you can initialize it.

Comment: It's true, but I thought the question was different?

Comment: @dbush All operands of an integer  consatnt expression shall be integer constants. In case of using the sizeof operator for a VLA then its result is not an intefer constant expression.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's true, however OP's second example has `int a[42]` so `sizeof(a)` is an integer constant and is the case they are asking about.

Answer (score 4):

“Evaluated statically” is not defined by the C standard.

If the array size is an *integer constant expression*, the array has a complete type with known constant size. Otherwise, it is a variable length array.

C 2018 6.6 6 defines *integer constant expression*:

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

So, in `char b[sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)]`, the question is whether `sizeof(a)` has a result that is an integer constant. C 6.5.3.4 2 tells us:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

Thus, if `a` is not a variable length array, the result is an integer constant. If `a` is a variable length array, the result is an integer but not, implicitly, an integer constant.

Thus, if `a` is a variable length array, then `char b[sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)]` declares a variable length array. The use of the ternary operator is not relevant, because the determination is based on the fact that the expression contains operands that are not in the list given in 6.6 6, and not on whether a ternary operator is present.

If `a` is not a variable length array, then `char b[sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)]` declares an array of known constant size. Again, the ternary operator is not relevant; the determination in 6.6 6 does not mention it. So the array size is a constant integer expression, and a conforming C implementation should accept `b` as an array of known constant size and permit its initialization.

There is one exception to the above. C 2018 6.6 10 says:

> An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

Thus, an implementation could in theory define `sizeof(a) > 10 ? 10 : sizeof(a)` to be a constant expression. Reliance on this would of course not be portable.